# Wait for a second async action before continuing redux observable

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I have two actions in a scenario:

`INITIATE` which triggers on a button click, and `FETCH_SUCCESS` which triggers when data has been stored in the state from an AJAX request called on page load.

The epic handling the `INITIATE` action requires the data from `FETCH_SUCCESS` being available in the state to work.

How can I write this epic so that it will 1) Do its logic as normal, as many times as it's been clicked after `FETCH_SUCCESS` has ran once, and 2) If clicked before `FETCH_SUCCESS`, wait for `FETCH_SUCCESS` to occur, and then continue to logic once the data is available / the success action has been ran.

There are at least a few easy approaches that solves this problem that I can think of, but don't want if this is possible to achieve with a single rxjx epic. For example: 1) Fail/retry flow where the epic simply checks if the data is available, and if not recursively calls itself with a small delay. 2) Make `INITIATE` set a flag in the state if `FETCH_SUCCESS` hasn't ran yet, and then listen to `FETCH_SUCCESS` and make it kick off `INITIATE` if this flag is set when it runs.

The only way I've come up with that don't include those two methods are writing it in two epics:

The version to handle `FETCH_SUCCESS` before `INITIATE` (happy path) looks like this:

```
export const initiateFirstEpic = action$ => action$
  .ofType(INITIATE)
  .skipUntil(Observable.of(FETCH_SUCCESS))
  .map(action => {
     return LogicAction();
  });
```

And the other to handle clicking too fast, making `INITIATE` happen before `FETCH_SUCCESS`:

```
export const successFirstEpic = action$ => action$
.ofType(INITIATE)
.switchMap(() =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_SUCCESS)
    .take(1)
    .map(action => {
       return LogicAction();
    })
);
```

This doesn't seem to work, nor does it really look the way I want it to. Is there a good way to achieve this? I am quite new to RxJS and Redux Observable, so the answer might be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest).

```
export const initiateEpic = action$ => Observable
  .combineLatest(action$.ofType(INITIATE), action$.ofType(FETCH_SUCCESS).take(1))
  .map(([action, _]) => {
     return LogicAction();
  });
```

Optionally use `take(1)` on `FETCH_SUCCESS` action `ofType` observable to prevent producing the `LoginAction` every time you get `FETCH_SUCCESS`

Comment: This solution did not work when I tried it. The observable indeed waited for the both actions to have been emitted, but after that the epic would trigger for every possible action. The resulting array would always be `['WHATEVER_ACTION', 'INITIATE', 'FETCH_SUCCESS']`. I want it to only trigger on `INITIATE` actions, but haven't found a proper solution yet. Exact same deal if I replace `combineLatest` with `withLatestFrom`.

Comment: Oooooops nevermind, I was using `action$.combineLatest(action$.ofType('INITIATE), action$.ofType('FETCH_SUCCESS'))` instead of `Observable.combineLatest(action$.ofType('INITIATE), action$.ofType('FETCH_SUCCESS'))`, which is why I was combining them with _any_ incoming action.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version based on @m1ch4ls but using the operator instead:

```
const initiateEpic = action$ =>
  action$
    .combineLatest(action$.ofType(FETCH_SUCCESS).take(1))
    .map(([initiateAction, fetch_success_action]) => {
      return LogicAction();
    });
```

Originally I didn't grasp that there was a static function `Observable.combineLatest(obs1$, obs2$)` and an operator `obs1$.combineLatest(obs2$)`, hence my comment to @m1ch4ls answer.